# Mockito.any() to match any instance of generics type T

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I'm trying to mock a void method to throw an exception every time. The method takes a `List<SomeClass>` as an argument. How to I pass its to `Mockito.any()`?

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception())
       .when(myClassInstanceSpy)
       .myVoidMethod(Mockito.any(List<SomeClass>.class)); // This fails!
```

---

Here's my class definition:

```
class MyClass {
    ... 
    public void myVoidMethod(List<SomeClass> scList) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify generics using explicit method types:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception())
   .when(myClassInstanceSpy)
   .myVoidMethod(Mockito.<List<SomeClass>>any());
```

Or with the handler for `List` in particular:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception())
   .when(myClassInstanceSpy)
   .myVoidMethod(Mockito.anyListOf(SomeClass.class));
```

Java 8 allows for parameter type inference, so if you're using Java 8, this may work as well:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception())
   .when(myClassInstanceSpy)
   .myVoidMethod(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: I'm not on Java 8, but `Mockito.any()` seems really handy. Thank you.

Comment: `Mockito.any()` is deprecated now.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Can you add a link? [`Mockito.any()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any--) is not deprecated as of 2.22. [`anyObject()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyObject--) is deprecated, and [`any(Class)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) changed semantics as of Mockito 2.x to be more like `isA(Class)` than `any()`, but as far as I can tell no `any` overload is deprecated.

Comment: @JeffBowman You are right. I confused that with `Matchers`, which *is* deprecated in favor of `ArgumentMatchers`.

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
Mockito.doThrow(new Exception())
   .when(myClassInstanceSpy)
   .myVoidMethod(Mockito.anyListOf(SomeClass.class));
```